# Del operator confusion

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, differentiation, covariance

The very first thing my textbook says is that the Del operator is defined as:
$$\vec{\nabla}=\vec{a}^i\nabla_i$$
Where $\nabla_i$ is the covariant derivative and " $\vec{a}^i$ is the curvilinear basis of the curvilinear coordinates $\xi ^i$". However I can't understand if that should be the dual basis (because of the upper index) or it is just written that way to obey einstein notation (upper and lower repeating) or maybe it is a mistake (I don't believe it to be). Can you help me clarify this?

Comment: What textbook??

Comment: Is this supposed to be the Hamiltonian operator in quantum mechanics?

Comment: Have you explored the gradient in spherical coordinates?

Comment: DanielC "Лекции по векторно и тензорно смятане за физици" It's in Bulgarian

Comment: @P.C.Spaniel I don't know that's what it says It's under the chapter for differential operators of a tensor field.

Comment: @DanielC https://drive.google.com/file/d/1snb8EGaFl96w1-Ti7c17ib2ICyhtjG1U/view That's the pdf. The thing I'm asking about is on 57-th page

Comment: Ok, so "Lectures on vector and tensor calculus for physicists". Maybe this should go in the mathematics  stackexchange? Because to me that looks like a normal directional derivative... I've never heard of it being called a Hamilton operator.

Comment: Regarding the placing of indeces. Derivatives have indeces down, vectors have indeces up, so everything in your expression makes sense, you don't need dual basis.

Comment: but the vector $\vec{x}$ is represented by covariant basis and contravariant components like: $x^i\vec{a}_i$ an covectors are written as $\vec{x}*=x_i\vec{a}^i$

Comment: *I've never heard of it being called a Hamilton operator.* Me neither.

Comment: @P.C.Spaniel *I've never heard of it being called a Hamilton operator* From [this page](https://jeff560.tripod.com/calculus.html): “The vector differential operator, now written $\nabla$ and called *nabla* or *del*, was introduced by William Rowan Hamilton”

Comment: While $\vec\nabla$ had indeed been introduced by Hamilton in contemporary english language literature it is called Del or nabla. So I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @P.C.Spaniel *indices*, not *indeces* (though "indexes" is also correct).